# Integrating variable inside xdmp:sql function XQuery

Tags: sql, xquery, marklogic

How can I ingest variables into a xmdp:sql() function like so:

```
let $name := ("foo")
return xdmp:sql("SELECT {$name} FROM TableName")
```

This code yields an error as on the curly brace: {$name} saying that it doesn't recognize the column. How can I get around this?

Comment: Beware of sql injection. If you could select column dynamically with sql based on a value, you could use variable bindings to use the variable inside the sql query. See 4th example of https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces don't escape into an expression context like [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates). Just concatenate the values:

```
xdmp:sql(concat("SELECT ", $name, " FROM TableName")
```

or, using the concatenation operator:

```
xdmp:sql("SELECT "||$name||" FROM TableName")
```